# search and select decimal numbers in a text file line

Tags: perl, awk, sed, numbers, head

I have xml textfiles which contain lines of multiple numbers (3) separated by tabs/spaces, from which I would like to select the each set of numbers separately.

From:

```
<tagname1>     110.0912    99.1234     55.1326   </tagname1>
```

Result:

```
110.0912
```

and:

```
99.1234
```

and:

```
55.1326
```

I would like to use sed, awk, grep, etc. perl is fine too. Seems simple, but can't figure out a cleaner line. I've tried:

```
more FILENAME | grep tagname1 | grep -E -o "[0-9]+*\.[0-9]+" |  head -n 1
```

Comment: What do you mean by `select the each set of numbers separately`? It looks like you don't want all 3 numbers printed, one per line, or you'd have specified your expected output as that instead of 3 separate output statements separated by `and:` and your posted command uses `head -n 1` to only print 1 line. Given that, though - what do you want?

Comment: I'd like to select each number separately; `head -n 1` outputs the first line - how can I select line 2, 3? thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -v which=2 '/<tagname1>(([0-9]*(\.[0-9]*)?)|[ \t])*<\/tagname1>/ {print $(which+1)}' input.txt
```

Select which number you want to be printed using the variable `which` in this example it will print the second number `which=2`

input.txt:

```
<tagname1>     110.0912    99.1234     55.1326   </tagname1>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -MRegexp::Common -nE 's/<.*?>//g; say for /($RE{num}{real})/g' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` `-o` option.

```
$ cat file
<tagname1>     110.0912    99.1234     55.1326   </tagname1>
```

```
$ grep -oE '\b[0-9.]+\b' file
110.0912
99.1234
55.1326
```

- `\b` defines a word boundary
- `[0-9.]+` is a character class suggesting match numbers and `.` one or more times
- `-o` option prints matched pattern only

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `awk`

```
awk '{print $2,$3,$4}' OFS="\n" file
110.0912
99.1234
55.1326
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file
<tagname1>     110.0912    99.1234     55.1326   </tagname1>
$ awk -v tag="tagname1" -v nr=1 '$0~"<"tag">"{print $(nr+1)}' file
110.0912
$ awk -v tag="tagname1" -v nr=2 '$0~"<"tag">"{print $(nr+1)}' file
99.1234
$ awk -v tag="tagname1" -v nr=3 '$0~"<"tag">"{print $(nr+1)}' file
55.1326
```